# Ubuntu 17.04 NGinx / Passenger

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, passenger

Following the tutorial [here](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04#nginx-passenger) brings up this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx-extras : Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 but it is not installable
```

I understand the tutorial is for `16.x`.

Because I'm installing `Ubuntu 17.04`, NGinx can't be installed on the new system.

--

Does anybody know a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/zesty/

```
sudo apt-get install -y dirmngr gnupg
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates

# Add our APT repository
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger zesty main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'
sudo apt-get update

# Install Passenger + Nginx module
sudo apt-get install -y libnginx-mod-http-passenger libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter nginx
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the answer has been marked as correct, provided solution doesn't work. If you look at https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/ comment, 17.04 version hasn't been released yet.

Thanks

Comment: I marked it correct because I thought it fixed my issue. As you have correctly pointed out, this was not the case.